# paypal payment which can be send to merchent account and can also request paymeny from merchnant

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a game site which have a feature like users can buy coins, For buy coins he can use PayPal. After making payment coins will added in hi account. And then any time he can request to change coins.

So my questions are

1. Which PayPal payment method should be used for it?
2. How can be payment will be sent in user account. Is site owner do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it can be done in one of two ways:

1. Reseller model: you collect the money into YOUR account and use PP to transfer the money to the merchant account (minus your commission or whatever)
2. The merchant opens an PP business account and provide you the API-credentials (not the user/pass to his account! the API creds!). Then you use his creds to place the orders and the money is collected in the merchant's account.